# PHP session_start() hangs.

Tags: php

I have several scripts in my in mysite root and they call each other freely, either with  a link that's clicked:

`<a href="http://main.com/login.php">login</a>`

or a header Location call:

`header("Location: http://main.com/index.php");`

login.php and index.php call sesssion_start() at the top so I can maintain common session variables  across the scripts.

Now I have the jQuery in index.php that needs to call another script in the site root,   util.php,  using ajax:

```
   ` galleryStatus2$.load('util.php', { 
      id         : g.user_id,
      op         : "register_keys",
      test_sk    : test_sk,   
      test_pk    : test_pk, 
      live_sk    : live_sk,  
      live_pk    : live_pk 
      },  `
```

If I put a session_start() at the top of util.php it hangs, so clearly I'm doing something wrong here.

Could someone shed some light on this situation and explain why I can't put a session_start at the top of util.php?

Thanks.

Comment: One particular situation in which this may occur is when two scripts try to access the same session at the same time (using a standard file-based session).

Comment: Try calling `session_close()` as soon as you know you're no longer modifying the session, and same goes for only calling `session_start()` when you need to access or write to the session. Alternatively if it is a file system issue as mentioned by @Jack, you can replace your session handler to write to a database engine.

Comment: There must be log when it hangs. Please attach it to the question.

Comment: More importantly, try to find out why there would be a script (needlessly) hanging on to a particular session. Scripts should run for only a short time.

Comment: @Scuzzy It's more important to establish whether a database backed session handler is indeed necessary, as those have their own quirks.

Comment: The Apache error log just reports a timeout: Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /var/www/php-bin/myname/php, referer: http://main.com/index.php
[Thu Jun 26 21:41:48 2014] The timeout specified has expired.

Comment: As far as "why one script would hang onto a session" consider that I'm running script A, which has the session, and then it does an ajax call to another script, say script B, that tries to get the session when script A is still running and waiting for a return from the ajax call. Script A never released the session.  Should that work?  Also, it seems like PHP should be telling us somewhere why session_start() in script B is hanging.